# how to deal with requests failed in scrapy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, multiprocess

I want to scrape information about a website. And I use the proxy IP like this:

```
def process_request(self, request, spider):
    item = random.choice(ippool)
    request.meta['proxy'] = "http://"+item['ip']
    request.meta['dont_redirect'] = True
```

But it will raise some error:

> DEBUG: Crawled (302), Crawled (403),
>   INFO: Ignoring response, 500 Internal Server Error

and so on. how can I solve those problems.

On the other hand, due to that's proxy IP, thus, it's slowly. If I want to add multiprocess in this. How should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To handle specific HTTP status codes you can define `handle_httpstatus_list`

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spider_name"
    handle_httpstatus_list = [500, and more here]
```

Now it will not show

```
INFO: Ignoring response, 500 Internal Server Error
```

instead it will hand over response to the relevent callback function.